# Yum skip-broken problem

Tags: yum, mysql, dependencies

I'm trying to install mysql-connector-odbc using yum. 
It gives me this error.

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64 0:5.3.6-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libodbcinst.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql-connectors-community)
           Requires: libodbc.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql-connectors-community)
           Requires: libodbcinst.so.2()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So I manually installed unixodbc which contains the required libodbc files and i tried running it with

```
yum install mysql-connector-odbc --skip-broken
```

which gives me another error.

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64 0:5.3.6-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libodbcinst.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.2()(64bit) for package: mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-1.el7.x86_64

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-1.el7.x86_64 from mysql-connectors-community
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the `CentOS` plugin **protectbase** this plugin will help when dealing with multiple 3rd party repos or just `EPEL/RPMForge`

You can use:

```
yum --disablerepo=[reponame] update
```

but that's a single use option if you'd like to protect your system continuously then I'd highly recommend the "protectbase"

```
"yum install yum-plugins-protectbase"
```

Then add `"protect=1"` on the repos you'd want to protect. Aka CentOS-Base
And add "`protect=0`" to epel.repo this should solve most common conflicts when dealing with 3rd party repositories.

I created a more in-depth guide on my blog here [Dealing with multiple repositories on `CentOS 4/5/6/7`](https://zm.nubes.ca/dealing-with-multiple-repositories-on-centos-4-5-7-with-yum-and-protectbase-plugin-1053/)

Answer (score 0):

Answering an old question, but in case someone runs across this:

The answer is that the `unixODBC` package provides those dependencies, which are part of the "rhel-7-server-rpms" RHEL channel, which appears to not be enabled on the host.